# How do I view the source tables of a cube?

Tags: db2, datasource, cognos-tm1

I have access to db2.

I also have access to some `Cognos Cubes` via `TM1` explorer.

Is it possible to find out the source tables for the cubes ?

For example, can I see what tables are used for the FST cube shown below ? and if possible even how the tables are joined etc
[image] . ?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you need access to the TurboIntegrator process that load your cube.

In your example, since it's an external source (Db2), the cube is loaded with a TurboIntegrator Process (process object in green). It's seems that you don't have the security access to view the process so you're not able to see the data source.

Hope it helps !